# How to display a different top banner for each category page in Woocommerce 4.7?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

**ONE TOP BANNER IMAGE PER CATEGORY PAGE**

I want to display a dedicated banner for each woocommerce category page, instead of the generic one applying globally to all category pages.

Wordpress and all extensions are updated.

I found the good overriding way, the category template `taxonomy-product_cat-{my_category_slug}.php` and wrote a simple condition to identify current category and override   `archive-product-{my_category_slug}.php` to display each category page.

My problem is that the background image is loaded in a CSS class `page_title`, but I can’t see the section it is applied to in the templates.

This is the section tag from the page source code :

```
<section class="page_title  ds s-pt-60 s-pb-60     s-pt-md-90 s-pb-md-90   s-pt-xl-150 s-pb-xl-150 cover-background s-overlay">
```

This is the `archive-product.php` HTML :

```
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
                <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php                     
                        woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php endif;
        /* ……… */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
</header>
```

I see the image section in the inspector of course, but can’t find it in templates and in the up sample I see only an H1 tag in the header.
The full template is [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/4.7/templates/archive-product.php).

I guess it might be in a hook, but I don’t find it in the woocommerce `includes` directory.

**What I tried :**

- Different plugins without success, most of them worked fine but added    banners to the main one without replacing it. Payware is OK but I don’t wanna spend $90 just to change top banners.
- Creating my own classes. This was useless since I found no way to attach it to each category page.
- Find a unique CSS selector to “catch” the section. I found none (I don’t say there are none).

**What I wouldn’t want to do :**

- Any barbarian inline JS
- Breaking the theme with excess of CSS fixes

How could I achieve this properly ?

Comment: This method is not optimal. You need to add a meta field for each product category, then save it when adding a new category or editing the category, and then check in each product category whether this category has a banner or not. If it has a banner, display it.

Comment: @HamidRezaYazdani Basically, Woocommerce doesn't give the option to chose one top banner per category. What you can do in the UI is defining one ** thumbnail ** per category. My theme use them to illustrate categories in shop page, but not to display on top of page in full width...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the best way since it involves manually editing HTML in functions.php, but for now this is how we're doing it.

File: Your theme or child theme's `functions.php`

Code:

```
// Inject custom HTML on specific category pages
function custom_category_html() {
  $page = get_queried_object();
  if ($page) {
    if ($page->term_id == 1) // Replace this with your intended Category ID #
      echo '
        <center><img src="/wp-content/uploads/.../some-image-for-category-1.jpg" /></center>
        <h2>Example Heading</h2>
        <p>Example paragraph</p>';
    else if ($page->term_id == 2) // ....and so on
      echo '...HTML for category ID 2';
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_category_html');
```

We use the term or category ID # instead of category name so that changing the category name won't break the code. Here is an example of what `get_queried_object()` looks like while viewing a category page:

```
$page = get_queried_object();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($page, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 279
    [name] => Shirts
    [slug] => shirts
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 279
    [taxonomy] => product_cat
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 277
    [count] => 54
    [filter] => raw
)
```

Take a look at pages like this for all available hooks on where to insert the custom HTML: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

In the example above, we're using `woocommerce_before_shop_loop` to display an image, heading, and short paragraph above a specific Category Archive Products display. For us we only need this method for a couple category views so it's acceptable for now. You could use PHP [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) if you have many categories to use this on, but granted it isn't the most beautiful approach.